# Android adb debugging: refreshing internal files directory

Tags: android, adb

I'm working on a project which involves saving files to the private internal app storage area. The device is connected via usb and adb.

When I save new files, they don't show up in the directory. I have to disconnect the usb cable, reconnect it, open a new explorer window and navigate to the folder to see the latest images. This takes ages, plus is going to wear out my usb port!

How can I refresh the files directory without having to reconnect my device please?

Comment: "I'm working on a project which involves saving files to the private internal app storage area" -- please provide a [mcve] demonstrating where and how you are saving these files. "When I save new files, they don't show up in the directory" -- you do not have any ability to see files on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) via a USB cable, except perhaps on rooted devices. Perhaps you are referring to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

Comment: If indeed you are referring to external storage, what you see on your desktop OS is what is known to the `MediaStore`, so you need to make sure that your newly-created files get indexed (e.g., via `MediaScannerConnection` and its `scanFile()` method). After that, you may need to do a "refresh" or "reload" in the file explorer to get it to pick up the changes.

Comment: Apologies for the incorrect terminology! The location I'm referring to (when viewed in windows) is /HTC One/Internal Storage/Android/data/com.example.myapp/files. Refreshing the folders doesn't show the new files.

Comment: That's what the Android SDK refers to as external storage. If your files are indexed by the `MediaStore`, and refresh isn't helping, then you have no choice but to examine that stuff via some other means. You could use an on-device file manager, or `adb shell` or the file explorer built into the Android Device Monitor (Tools > Android > Android Device Monitor from the Android Studio main menu).

Comment: i think when the device is connected to USB, the storage memory somehow got mounted on the PC, which makes it unavailable (at least temporary) for writing operations, i faced this with HTC device where write operations got delayed and sometimes i had to remove the USB to make it happen, not sure what is this.

Comment: P.S: although i wasn't getting any errors or exceptions that write failed or device not ready ... etc, it was all complete with no errors, but no files appeared, i used mobile-app FileManager, i tried to browser to folder using PC.